# Same stylesheet_link_tag...one give a path with /assets/, one gives a path with /stylesheets/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
...
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap", "bootstrap-embed" %>
...
```

Is somehow spitting out this in the html it delivers to the browser:

```
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap-embed.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Why are the paths different?

I've tried this, too:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap-embed" %>
```

With the same unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had misspelled the filename: "boostrap-embed.css".  I don't know why the asset pipeline decided that that meant it needed a different path, but it did.

Comment: I think it's fallback to old way to keep assets in public, so rails think that it's static file in `public/stylesheets` folder